# Problema com função split em C

Tags: c, string, ponteiro

Oi, eu estou estudando a linguagem C e me deparei com um problema de ponteiro em uma função de quebra de string.
Eu uso a versão **4.8.4 do GCC**.
O valor de entrada que resulta em erro é "1234|123|123|123" 4/3/3/3, já outros valores como "1234|123|123|1234" 4/3/3/4, passam sem erro.

Segue o anexo do código.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char **split(const char *str, const char *chrs){
    char to_list[strlen(str)];
    char *ssplit;
    int x=0,y=0;
    char **res = 0;

    for(y=0;y<strlen(str);y++){
        if(str[y] == chrs[0])
            x++;
    }

    strcpy(to_list, str);
    ssplit = strtok(to_list, chrs);
    res = (char **) malloc(sizeof(char*)*(x+1));
    y=0;

    while(ssplit){
        res[y] = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(ssplit));
        strcpy(res[y],ssplit);
        y++;
        ssplit= strtok(NULL, chrs);
    }

    return res;
}
```

Comment: É importante identar seu código corretamente. O código acima pode ser sintáticamente válido, mas fica difícil das pessoas lerem.

Comment: Independente dessa função funcionar - como as funções que chamam ela vão saber o tamanho do vetor res retornado? Qualquer um consumindo o resultado dessa função não saberiaonde parar. Voce tem como colocar um programa minimamente completo que use essa função? (resolvivel fazendo o tamanho de res ser `((sizeof(char*)*(x+2)) ` em vez de `(x + 1)` - e colocando-se um NULL na última posição)

Comment: isso realmente ajudaria a identificar a posição final, mas estava trabalhando com valores fixos, e o erro se originava por causa do tipo de entrada

Answer (score 1):

```
char to_list[strlen(str)];
```

O array `to_list` tem espaço para strings de até `strlen(str) - 1` de comprimento. Se lá puseres mais caracteres que isso (incluindo o `'\0'`) invocas Comportamento Indefinido.

```
strcpy(to_list, str); // BANG!, tentativa de colocar um caracter a mais em to_list
```